# Can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

So I downloaded the SQL suite with the server and I'm trying to connect to my server through Visual Studio database explorer.

I select:

Data source: Microsoft SQL Server (`SqlClient`)

Server name: ??

but I tried everything for the server name, and it doesn't show me a list of databases on that server, just comes up empty (tried localhost/root/DraftDB which is the name of my server in the MySQL workbench, nothing works.

Does anyone know how I can connect to a server from Visual Studio?

Comment: MySQL != Microsoft SQL server (MSSQL)

Comment: So what is MySQL used for then?

Comment: It's just another database engine .. benefit is "it's free" *and* it runs on non-Windows operating systems. Now, if you're using MySQL Workbench to talk to MSSQL (if that's possible, I don't know or really care) then that's fine, but make sure to use the appropriate tags :) The "Server Name" refers to just the Server Instance (but *not* the database). You can view the MSSQL instances using the "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled connection by TCP/IP or Named Pipes in the SQL Configuration Manager, on the server where MSSQL is located, under the Client Protocols section for your SQL Server instance. Then you should be able to connect via IP or name as long as you include the DB instance name.

Example:

DB Server IP: 192.168.1.101

DB Name: MYDBSERVER

SQL Instance name: MSSQL

Connection via TCP/IP is: 192.168.1.101/MSSQL

Connection via name is: \\MYDBSERVER\MSSQL